# How to get row from source data in Handsontable

Tags: handsontable

In short, I need to 'programmatically' select a row (all cells) in a Handsontable from a source data.

My original idea is to get the row (and/or cell), then call the `selectCell` method, but I'm stuck.  I don't know how to get the row from a source data.

I have one of the columns that represent an id.  I suppose I could get all values of that column, loop in them and seek the one that has the id I'm looking for, store the index as the "row" index and then I'd have my row.  That's seem a bit harsh.

Is such a feature supported in the Handontable library ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Search plugin seems like the perfect approach: http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.1/demo-search-for-values.html?_ga=1.221391256.1663141125.1437415399

It returns the rows/cells that I need.

Comment: there are many many ways of doing this but I'm glad you found the search plugin to be a good solution

Comment: Yeah, as it turns out the search plugin won't seem to really help in the end because it searches all cells, but I'll figure something out.  As I load the data, I store the ids to keep track of their according row and there you go.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: sure but I really suggest you be careful when using physical indeces to reference your data if you decide to use the column sorting pluging. you will notice that your code will break in this case becasue this sorting pluging won't modify your source data but instead use logical indeces. there's a very detailed page with this issue if you run into it

Comment: Thanks for the notification.